# Find and replace a string in MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress

I wish to update tables in a WordPress database, and I am confident with what I wish to achieve, and it won't do any damage, I am struggling to achieve what I want.

in the post_content field there is:

> ```
> <img class="aligncenter  wp-image-1603" title="365 Days of Robot, Day 4" alt="365 Days of Robot, Day 41"
> src="http://www.silversnaps.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/041-365-Days-of-Robot.jpg"
> />
> ```

Now I wish to replace the img class with

> ```
> <img class="aligncenter  wp-image-1603 img-responsive"
> ```

I know how to update the table - but I can't figue out how to match what I wish to update.
I would like to add the class 'img-responsive' at tne end of the class.

> ```
> UPDATE your_table SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<img
> class="%"', '<img Class"% img-responsive') WHERE post_content LIKE
> '%<img class"%"'
> ```

Comment: Why don't you instead update the theme's functions to add the class when rendering the post_content? You can then keep the database as-is. Or there is a Search and Replace plugin for wordpress that will achieve this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/. I assume you want to do with all images in post content or just where they have the aligncenter class?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this one field how about

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<img class="%"', '<img class="% img-responsive') WHERE post_content LIKE '%aligncenter  wp-image-1603%'
```

Or if you need something broader, such as all content images, how about

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<img class="', '<img class="img-responsive ') WHERE post_content LIKE '%<img class="%'
```

That will assume of course the class is the first attribute of all your image tags.

**By the way:** be sure you run any scripts through a SELECT first to make sure you are fetching what you want!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use wildcard `%` in your REPLACE.
Try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d349f/1/0)

```
UPDATE your_table SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,'" title="',1),'<img class="',-1),
                                                   CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content,'" title="',1),'<img class="',-1),' img-responsive'))
WHERE post_content like '%<img class="%"'
```